# Set language of standard .NET exception messages

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, localization, xamarin.android, currentculture

(how) is it possible to display standard .NET exception messages like the SocketException "Network is unreachable" in another language?

I thougth it depends on the CurrentCulture but in my App (Android & iOS) the message is always in English even though my CurrentCulture says "de-DE".

Background is that i want to display some exception messages in dialogs.

Hint: I am using native Xamarin and not Forms.

Kind regards

Oliver

Answer (score 1):

In .Net Desktop or Web App in general we use a simple set like this :

`Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo("en-us");`

But don't sure if this is a good practice with Xamarin

Comment: This is how you do it in Xamarin too to make the .Net part of the world load the right language

Comment: I guess the mentioned SocketException Messages are not localized in Xamarin/Mono which is why setting UICulture has no effect. See here [link](https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/91288cad6a6c093ee1ca9b072219144c8bac9f75/mcs/class/System/ReferenceSources/Win32Exception.cs)